# Can I change a plugins value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, graphael, justgage

Working with 'justGuage' http://justgage.com/ a js plugin and thought it would be neat if the user could update and save their respective interactions with the guage via the browser.

Noticed on the setup page the developer has the following...

```
<script>
  var g = new JustGage({
  id: "gauge", 
  value: 67, 
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  title: "Visitors"
  });
```

This isn't a object right? It's just params which you input to change the look of the guage...

I thought i'd somehow hook into the justGuage object/plugin like this...

```
<script>
     $('#increment').click(function (){
       var upValue = g1.value;
       return upValue++;
});
    </script>
```

Bear with the above is sort of pseudo code based on me giving it a shot as I am a noob in js/jQuery...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thats an object that contains values, you could initialize it the same way with `var g = new JustGage(obj)` where `obj` is something like `var obj = {id: "gauge", ...}`

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 1):

The lib provides a `refresh` method for this purpose.

In the latest code on github, refresh will update the `config.value` automatically, however the latest packaged code released is quite a bit older and does not, so you'll have to increment the value manually.

This will do the trick:

```
$('#increment').click(function (){
  g.refresh(++g.config.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pDQ8K/

Comment: THANKS so much. It worked with .config.value, however it doesn't continue to fire after that initial click...

Comment: I discovered that the packaged code is almost a year behind the github repo.  The newer code will update the value automatically on refresh, the packaged version will not.  See edit.